# Gimp (GAP) on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: files, gimp, animations, extract

There's a picture of what comes up.

[image: 1]

This comes up every time I try to extract videorange. I've tried .mp4, .MPG, and .flv files and it says the same thing each time. I looked it up on youtube, and .mp4 worked for someone else. I'm pretty sure that the problem must be beyond that but I don't know what it is.

Comment: 10.04 Desktop support is no longer on topic here, as 10.04 Desktop is past EOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand about packaging and digging through the source and configure options, this functionality does not work because the program was packaged as a [Debian Free Software Guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Free_Software_Guidelines) (DFSG) compatible package. You know, the reason why you need to install the `(k)ubuntu-restricted-extras` meta packages.

The following lines in the file `debian/rules` in the source package seem to be the culprit here:

```
DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS := \
        --disable-audio-support \
        --disable-libxvidcore \
        --disable-libavformat \
        --disable-libmpeg3
```

Which literally disables the complete functionality you are looking for. I checked with a WEBM/VP8 and Theora video file without audio that I converted by myself with ffmpeg - doesn't work.

I could only find the [dfsg packages on lauchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp-gap) and searching on the Internet for "ubuntu gimp-gap" packages only brought up the same results.

Your only choice at the moment is to repackage the package yourself ([see the packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/)). Throw out all the lines mentioned above and probably modify the first line of `extern_libs/configure_options_ffmpeg.txt` to look like this:

```
--enable-shared --enable-static --disable-mmx --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
```

Besides: Please update to the current LTS (12.04).

---

Bugs reported:

[Extract video range feature is broken in Gimp-GAP](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp-gap/+bug/1221786)

[Mplayer based extraction does not work with Mplayer2 or mpv](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp-gap/+bug/1221788)

Comment: I cannot update now, as my computer doesn't exactly support it (I'll cross that hurdle when I have too). If I were to repackage it, how difficult would it be on a scale of 1 to 10? And how would I go about repackaging it?

Comment: I'm just trying to get into this packaging stuff again. Years ago I would have rated the guide as an 8, but it looks like it got easier.

Comment: Crap, I know nothing about this, but its a start. Thank you!

Comment: Currently setting up pbuilder... may be you get a working package in a day or earlier. Can't make any promises though.

Comment: Sorry I have to give up on this, it's more than just changing some config flags and rebuilding.